# How to use two Gtk.IconLookupFlags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I want to find an application icon with two flags (FORCE_SIZE and NO_SVG), but I have no idea how to do it!

I have already tried the following:

```py
icon = Gio.content_type_get_icon(mimetype)
theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
info = theme.choose_icon(icon.get_names(), size, Gtk.IconLookupFlags.NO_SVG, Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SIZE)
```

Returns error, because I give more than 3 arguments;

```py
icon = Gio.content_type_get_icon(mimetype)
theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
info = theme.choose_icon(icon.get_names(), size, (Gtk.IconLookupFlags.NO_SVG, Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SIZE))
```

Returns error, because it asks for FLAG type and not Tuple

```py
icon = Gio.content_type_get_icon(mimetype)
theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
info = theme.choose_icon(icon.get_names(), size, Gtk.IconLookupFlags.NO_SVG and Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SIZE)
```

Returns icons with wrong sizes.

I already tried searching but couldn't find any answer for my problem

Comment: 1) *how to combine flags*  and *icons are of wrong sizes* are two different questions and should be posted as different questions. 2) In python `&` and `and` (just like `|` and `or`) are different operators, the first one is binary and second is boolean. You need **binary or**, as stated in the answer below.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Thank you so much for your answer, still the size being returned is wrong... Sorry for being a little rude in my answer, yesterday was a not the best day, for me, the combination of flags isn't working and didn't knew how to combine them, neither why isn't working. Thanks for your answer, once more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bitwise OR the flags to combine them.

```
flags = Gtk.IconLookupFlags.NO_SVG | Gtk.IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SIZE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However when searching for Nautilus it outcomes a 256x256 icon, as seen in the output:/usr/share/icons/Yaru/256x256/apps/org.gnome.Nautilus.png

Comment: Have you any idea why or how to solve it? Even with FORCE_SIZE can gtk return a bigger icon?

Comment: @GustavoMachado please don't post further questions as comments, ask a new question instead.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I was restating my question, thank you